# Is this IntPtr pointing to allocated unmanaged memory or not?

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmanaged, unmanaged-memory

First, I allocate memory and get the pointer:

```
IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
```

Then, I try to release the memory pointed by my pointer:

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointer);
```

But in my application it raises sometimes a fatal unknown exception with just this explaination: "a memory fragment has been damaged". I guess this is because I try to free a pointer that points to a memory block already disallocated by freeing another pointer...

My question is: using the IntPtr pointer, is there any way to check if the memory block is still allocated or has been already disallocated ?

Comment: It cannot have been freed by "another pointer", only through (a copy of) this one. And that makes it a matter of pure program logic.

Comment: Henk is right; the solution is not to ask "is this pointer valid?" That leads to the following situation: you allocate the pointer. Somehow it gets freed -- that's where your bug is by the way -- then *someone else* allocates memory and they get *the same pointer*. You then ask "is this pointer valid?" and it says "yes", and you free someone else's memory.  Don't try to work around your bug; **find your bug and fix it**.

Comment: It is also possible that you're getting the error not because the block has been double-freed, but because you've written to memory before or after the valid size of the block. Try this: when you allocate the block, allocate it sixteen bytes too large. Put eight bytes, say, `DEADBEEFBAADF00D` -- easy to see in the debugger! -- into the extra eight at the beginning and the end, and then add eight bytes to the pointer before you use it. You now have a valid buffer surrounded by known bytes. When you go to free it, subtract eight bytes and check to see if the sentinels are still there.

Comment: @EricLippert What do you mean by "someone else" ? You mean an other application ?

Comment: @EricDavid: I mean other code in your application. Remember the so-called "global heap" is global to *your process*, not to *the operating system*.  The name is left over from Windows 3, in which it was possible to allocate memory shared by every application -- in Win3 you'd use `LocalAlloc` for memory that you did not intend to share between applications. Nowadays they do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good way to free your pointer is Marshal.FreeHGlobal(), so if it is disallocated, it's a logic problem, but you could do it in a try/catch, so it's already disallocated if you get into the catch exception.

Comment: And then what? Now you've caught an exception in a program with a corrupted heap. The right thing to do here is to log the exception and then shut down the application before any more harm is done.